# Foreach into foreach with an Sqlite command C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I want to make something like

```
var records = db.Receipts.Where(re => re.Id.Equals(1));

foreach (var record in records)
{
     //This is a relational table between the product table and the receipt table
     var proRec = db.ProductsReceipts.Where(re => re.ReceiptId.Equals(record.Id));

     foreach (var item in proRec)
     {
          //Something
     }
}
```

this show me an error: "cannot set commandText while a DataReader is active". I know whats the error means, but im need to make that loop. Any idea?

PD: im using linq2db, nuget, etc

Comment: use `.ToList()` to finish fetching data from your first query. or learn how to use `Join` to only _send_ one query in the first place.

Comment: boucle = loop en Anglais

Comment: Rather than Join, `.Include(...)` navigation properties.

Comment: Ey @FranzGleichmann your solution (query.ToList()) is simple and works, but, between query.ToList() or do a join query, whats is the most efficient action?

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect it to look more like:

```
var records = db.Receipts.Include(r => r.ProductsReceipts).Where(re => re.Id.Equals(1));

foreach (var record in records)
{
  foreach (var item in record.ProductsReceipts)
  {
      //Something
  }
}
```

If you're going to do something with the Product connected to the other side of the ProductsReceipts, then load that too:

```
var records = db.Receipts
  .Include(r => r.ProductsReceipts).
    .ThenInclude(pr => pr.Product)
  .Where(re => re.Id.Equals(1));
```

Comment: While this code is correct, there is no explaination as to why this is better. You have just done the work for the OP without explaining why they should be doing it this way